# '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' in my guess the number game

Tags: python, input

In my guess the number program it gives me the error: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' on line 26 in *main*. I would be grateful if someone helped me with this, Thank you.

```
import random
guesses = 0


def higher(guesses):
    print("Lower")
    gueeses += 1


def lower(guesses):
    print("Higher")
    guesses += 1


def correct(guesses):
    print("You got it correct!")
    print("It was {0}".format(number))
    guesses += 1


def _main_(guesses):
    print("Welcome to guess the number")
    number = random.randint(1, 100)
    while True:
        guess = input("Guess a number: ")
        if guess > number:
            lower(guesses)
        elif guess < number:
            higher(guesses)
        elif guess == number:
            correct(guesses)
            while True:
                answer = input("Would you like to play again? Y or N: ")
                if answer == "Y":
                    break
                elif answer == "N":
                    exit()
                else:
                    exit()


_main_(guesses)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `input` returns a string. You need to convert your input to a numeric type, in this case integer.

Replace:

```
guess = input("Guess a number: ")
```

With:

```
guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
```

You may also wish to validate user input to ensure that you have actually been provided with a valid integer. For this you should see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).